# excel found unreadable content while using style in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to set background color of a call based on cell value, But i am getting error when i use the below code

```
function bgColor($cell,$color){
 global $F; 
$F->getStyle($cell)->applyFromArray(
            array(
                'fill' => array(
                    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                    'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $color),
                        'endcolor' => array('rgb' => $color)
                    //'color' => array('argb' => $color)
                    )
            )
    );
}
```

if i use rgb the following error occurs

Repaired Part: /xl/styles.xml part with XML error.  (Styles) Load error. Line 2, column 934.
Removed Feature: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)
Removed Records: Style from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)

if i use argb the first cell is filled with black color, while the argument passed to the color is yellow.

Ca anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: What is the actual value of `$color`? Is it really a string containg the word `yellow` rather than an `rgb` value?

Comment: Its hex value for yellow color "#FFFF00"

Comment: Get rid of the leading `#`, just set $color = 'FFFF00'; Excel isn't a web page